# super() is the first line of class2 but giving illegal start of type

Tags: java, netbeans, super

I am using netBeans7.3.1 and getting error *illegal start of type * even though I have written super() as the irst line of class2.

```
package javaapplication9;

class class1 {

    class1() {
        System.out.print("class1 constructor");
    }

    void msg() {
        System.out.println("Hello class1");
    }
}

class class2 extends class1 {

    super();

    void msg() {

        System.out.println("Hello class1");

    }
}

public class JavaApplication9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class1 obj = new class1();
        obj.msg();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the constructor.

```
class class2 extends class1 {

    class2() {
        super();
    }

    void msg() {

        System.out.println("Hello class1");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be inside the constructor of your sub class.

```
class class2 extends class1 {

    class2() {
        super();
    }
```

So that it invokes your super class constructor when you create subclass object.

[Please prefer to read it before proceeding.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that it is also completely unnecessary. The compiler will insert a `super();` call automatically if you don't, so you can just skip the Constructor declaration here.

Comment: @Keppil True. Seems OP trying to just started examples of using super constructor. Stumbled with where it should be placed.